# Filter entities with a field from another entity in linq query c#

Tags: entity-framework, linq, filter, left-join

I wanna join some tables in linq query. The problem is that I can not filter one of entities with field of another entity. In the below code b.createDate is not defiend, how can I do this query in linq?

```
From a in context.A
Join b in context.B
On a.Id equals b.AId
Join c in context.C.where(x => 
x.createDate >= b.createDate)
On b.Id equals c.BId into g
From result in 
g.DefaultIfEmpty()
Select result
```

Comment: This is a strange mixture of VB-ish and C#-ish code, but not valid. Please post code that actually compiles and runs. Also explain what's the meaning of *b.createDate is not defined*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `from` instead of join in this case. As documented: [Collection selector references outer in a non-where case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause)

```cs
var query =
    from a in context.A
    join b in context.B on a.Id equals b.AId
    from c in context.C
      .Where(x => x.BId == b.Id && x.createDate >= b.createDate)
      .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select c;
```